# How to add the correct signature to SOAP request in jmeter

Tags: web-services, ssl, soap, jmeter

I needed to apply both message and transport certificates to a request in Jmeter. 
I setup jmeter-wssecurity (addon) to enable me to sign the SOAP request and setup TLS in system.properties.
TLS shows that the cert is loaded OK.

Below is snapshot of the setup:

[image][image]

I'm new to certs and so require assistance in both understanding what the actual error means and what can be done to resolve it?

Any assistance welcomed

Comment: Now added the certificate alias to signer, now just getting a SSL exception error - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Comment: Please add jmeter tag because your question may be not related to specific jmeter 3.2 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manged to resolve the issue by viewing the keystore information to get the signature algorithm and the alias information.

The specify the correct security assertion withing the request.